# How to graph $\frac{(x+3)}{(x+1)}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, graphing-functions

I'm not looking for plotting values. I mean something which can be done without it.

For example, for the function $f(x) = mx + b$, we can use the slope $m$ and the y-intercept $b$ to easily graph the function, but the function given above seems impossible to graph like that. Any hints?

Comment: Have you learned about horizontal and vertical asymptotes?

Comment: Not really, but I know that they are the ones which do not touch the x or the y axes, correct?

Comment: Three things:  1)at very large negative and positive x, the function gets close to 1. 2) At x=-1 the function "blows up".  Just below -1 the funtion approaches neg  infinity.  Just after -1 it is approaches pos infinity. 3) at x =-3 the function is 0. Putting those three ideas together we see that the function is less than one and tapers toward 1 at neg extremes.  It crosses the x axis at x =-3 than it dives toward neg infinity.  It's not defined at x =-1 but imediately after x=-1 it plunges down from pos infinity.  It stabilizes and then tends toward but us always more than 1.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$$y=\frac{x+3}{x+1}=\frac{(x+1)+2}{x+1}=1+\frac2{x+1}$$

$$y=\frac2x \rightarrow y=\frac2{x+1}\rightarrow y= 1+\frac2{x+1}$$

[image]

[image]

[image]